# Self-hosted mass-mail sending software

Tags: gratis, open-source, email, self-hosted, newsletter

Is there a good self-hosted newsletter application in PHP, Node.js, Python or Ruby?

Desired features:

- Import subscribers with CSV
- Export subscribers to CSV
- Batch sending
- Multiple newsletter management
- Click tracking per subscriber
- Analytics / graphs
- Email templates

Services like MailChimp offer a hosted version but I need an open-source project that I can modify to fit my needs and which I can host myself (on Linux).

#### I already found a few:

- [Laravel4-Newsletter-Application](https://github.com/kJamesy/Laravel4-Newsletter-Application/)
- [django-newsletter | Newsletter application for the Django web framework](https://github.com/dokterbob/django-newsletter)
- [silverstripe-newsletter |  SilverStripe Newsletter Module](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-newsletter)
- [newsletter | TYPO3 extension to send newsletter](https://github.com/Ecodev/newsletter)

But all of them lack some of the desired features.

Comment: Maybe [Mailtrain](https://mailtrain.org) (node.js) might be of interest to some ([GitHub](https://github.com/andris9/mailtrain)).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### [Sendy](http://sendy.co) <sup>[(demo)](http://sendy.co/demo/login)</sup>

I run this on my Ubuntu Linux server. It's awesome and I've always gotten great support.

> - Import subscribers with CSV

Yep, you can do this. I make fairly extensive use of this feature.

> - Export subscribers to CSV

Yes.

> - Batch Sending

Not sure what you mean - but if you mean that it can send email to multiple people with one click, yes. I currently have a list of ~15k subscribers, and my t1.micro (really small) server doesn't choke on it.

> - Multiple newsletter management

You can have multiple brands, multiple lists within a brand, multiple newsletters for each list (and multiple lists each newsletter is sent to), and even have scheduled emails that are sent to a subscriber after they've been subscribed for *x* days.

> - Click tracking per subscriber
> - Analytics / Graphs

For a list:

[image]

And for a single email, you get stats/pie charts on how many people opened it, what country they're in, what they did *after* they opened the email, what links they clicked, etc. I can't show a screenshot of this for obvious reasons, but it's just as beautiful as the rest of the app.

> - Email Templates

**No**, these aren't included *in* Sendy. I personally like to have my emails have a 'personal look' - no fancy colors, borders, etc. But [there are plenty available on the Internet](https://www.google.com/#q=html+email+templates).

---

It's **not open source**, but it's *very* easy to modify with even a very slight grasp of PHP.  I've done it. They don't obfuscate the code or do anything evil like that:

> **Are Sendy's files obfuscated?**
>
> Sendy's files are not obfuscated except for the installation and functions file. You can edit the source code for your own personal use without needing these two files.

It's currently $60, and it's well worth it. It includes a fancy API that I make extensive use of from my apps, and it simply *looks good*. It is designed to run off [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), with a grand price of $0.10 per thousand emails. It can also run off straight SMTP from your server, though. I prefer SES myself.

You can try out a live demo [here](http://sendy.co/demo/login).

Comment: Though it is still not free. I am looking for a free solution. This is something to be noted though. Thanks.