# Tool to send personalized mails

Tags: email, marketing

We need a mailing tool to send highly individual mails to customers, triggered via an api. The mails should have a content like "It's been a while, here is what you missed:", followed by stuff that is individual to each recipient. Along with the usual options to unsubscribe from these mails, etc.

If you know trello, you know what I mean, they send mails like these to notify you of new activities that you are tagged in etc.

Can you recommend a service that allows for this?

Comment: You could use SendGrid. It allows you to do everything that you have stated in the question. However it is a web service and the number of emails is limited for the free version. Is this okay? Checkout https://sendgrid.com/

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be free. I'll check out sendgrid, thanks. But will it really work in my case? I need a mailinglist that users can subscribe / unsubscribe to. If a user has not logged in for a while I want to send a mail to him containing some stuff that he *personally* might be interested in. So it is content per recipient, but not really a transactional mail

Comment: Related questions you might wish to check: [Self-hosted mass-mail sending software](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/3676/185) / [Free newsletter software for a small business?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/55/185) / [Email List / Hosted Listserv / Google Groups / Yahoo Groups alternative](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/24806/185) / [Email list/group without the need to make an account](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/17988/185) / [more](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=mailing+list+answers%3A1).